# sending audio via bluetooth a2dp source esp32

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, esp32

I am trying to send measured i2s analogue signal (e.g. from mic) to the sink device via Bluetooth instead of the default noise.
Currently I am trying to change the `bt_app_a2d_data_cb()`

```
static int32_t bt_app_a2d_data_cb(uint8_t *data, int32_t i2s_read_len)
{
    if (i2s_read_len < 0 || data == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    char* i2s_read_buff = (char*) calloc(i2s_read_len, sizeof(char));

    bytes_read = 0;
    i2s_adc_enable(I2S_NUM_0);
    while(bytes_read == 0)
    {
    i2s_read(I2S_NUM_0,  i2s_read_buff, i2s_read_len,&bytes_read, portMAX_DELAY);
    }
    i2s_adc_disable(I2S_NUM_0);

// taking care of the watchdog//
    TIMERG0.wdt_wprotect=TIMG_WDT_WKEY_VALUE;
    TIMERG0.wdt_feed=1;
    TIMERG0.wdt_wprotect=0;

    uint32_t j = 0;
    uint16_t dac_value = 0;

// change 16bit input signal to 8bit 
    for (int i = 0; i < i2s_read_len; i += 2) {
        dac_value = ((((uint16_t) (i2s_read_buff[i + 1] & 0xf) << 8) | ((i2s_read_buff[i + 0]))));
        data[j] = (uint8_t) dac_value * 256 / 4096;
        j++;
    }

// testing for loop
    //uint8_t da = 0;
        //for (int i = 0; i < i2s_read_len; i++) {
        //  data[i] = (uint8_t) (i2s_read_buff[i] >> 8);//  & 0xff;
            //   da++;
           //  if(da>254) da=0;
        //}

    free(i2s_read_buff);
    i2s_read_buff = NULL;


    return i2s_read_len;
}
```

I can hear the sawtooth sound from the sink device.
Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

your data can be an array of some float digits representing analog signals or analog signal variations, for example, a 32khz sound signal contains 320000 float numbers to define captures sound for every second. if your data have been expected to transmit in offline mode you can prepare your outcoming data in the form of a buffer plus a terminator sign then send buffer by Bluetooth module of sender device which is connected to the proper microcontroller. for the receiving device, if you got terminator character like "\r" you can process incoming buffer e.g. for my case, I had to send a string array of numbers but I often received at most one or two unknown characters and to avoid it I reject it while fulfill receiving container.

[how to trim unknown first characters of string in code vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604765/how-to-trim-unknown-first-characters-of-string-in-code-vision)

if you want it in online mode i.e. your data must be transmitted and played concurrently. you must consider delays and reasonable time to process for all microcontrollers and devices like Bluetooth, EEprom iCs and...

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on a project "a2dp source esp32".

I'm playing a wav-file from spiffs.

If the wav-file is 44100, 16-bit, stereo then you can directly write a stream of bytes from the file to the array `data[ ]`.
When I tried to write less data than in the `len`-variable and return less (for example 88), I got an error, now I'm trying to figure out how to reduce this buffer because of big latency (`len`=512).

Also, the data in the array `data[ ]` is stored as stereo.

Example: read data from file to data[ ]-array:

```
size_t read;
read = fread((void*) data, 1, len, fwave);//fwave is a file
if(read<len){//If get EOF, go to begin of the file
    fseek(fwave , 0x2C , SEEK_SET);//skip wav-header 44bytesт
    read = fread((void*) (&(data[read])), 1, len-read, fwave);//read up
}
```

If file mono, I convert it to stereo like this (I read half and then double data):

```
int32_t lenHalf=len/2;
read = fread((void*) data, 1, lenHalf, fwave);
if(read<lenHalf){
    fseek(fwave , 0x2C , SEEK_SET);//skip wav-header 44bytesт
    read = fread((void*) (&(data[read])), 1, lenHalf-read, fwave);//read up

}
//copy to the second channel
uint16_t *data16=(uint16_t*)data;
for (int i = lenHalf/2-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    data16[(i << 1)] = data16[i];
    data16[(i << 1) + 1] = data16[i];
}
```

I think you have got sawtooth sound because:

1. your data is mono?
2. in your "`return i2s_read_len;`" `i2s_read_len` less than `len`
3. you `// change 16bit input signal to 8bit`, in the array data[ ] data as 16-bit: 2ByteLeft-2ByteRight-2ByteLeft-2ByteRight-...

I'm not sure, it's a guess.